# Will eager loading a Linq to Entity query before rendering my view slow things down?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When my view is rendered I will need to fetch location data (array of long/lat coordinates) coming from my viewmodel. I'll use Javascript to read these values and plot them in a Google Map. Currently I'm fetching results that contain the location data but I'm not sure how to efficiently get the location data out of the results and place them into another property in my view model. Should this be eagerly loaded, lazy loaded, etc.? I'm kinda a newbie to Linq and EF.

I have a view model that looks something like this

```
public class YogaSpaceListViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<YogaSpaceResults> YogaSpaces { get; set; }
    // I need to put all LocationPoints data from the query results into a collection here
    //public some collection here LocationResults { get; set; }
}
```

FYI IPagedList inherits from IEnumerable.

When I fetch the results here is my query. I put the results into an annonymous type 'YogaSpaceResults' and you can see that it contains the 'LocationPoints' data that I want to store in my viewmodel.

```
var events = (from u in context.YogaSpaceEvents
    orderby u.YogaSpace.Address.LocationPoints.Distance(myLocation)
    where
        (u.DateTimeScheduled >= classDate) &&
        (u.YogaSpace.Address.LocationPoints.Distance(myLocation) <= 8047)
            select new YogaSpaceResults 
            {   
                LocationPoints = u.YogaSpace.Address.LocationPoints,
                Title = u.YogaSpace.Overview.Title,
                Summary = u.YogaSpace.Overview.Summary,
                Date = u.DateTimeScheduled
            }).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

and in my view I'm doing something like this

```
@foreach (var space in Model.YogaSpaces)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>@space.Title</h4>
            <div>
                @space.Summary
                <br/>
                @space.Date
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to efficiently get the location data out of the results and place them into another property in my view model. Should this be eagerly loaded, lazy loaded, etc.?

they are already loaded from the db when you execute ToPagedList, so you don't need to load them and everything will be done in memory

you can have something quite simple like

```
public IEnumerable<LocationPoint> LocationResults {
    get{
        return YogaSpaces.Select(ys => ys.LocationPoints)
    }
}
```

By the way, it seems you already fetch the data from the DB in an efficient way (you project the needed properties in your view model using a single query, which is much more efficient than lazy loading or eager loading) So you can easily keep your current code.

Note, if you find that your query is too slow, maybe a spatial index is missing for this condition

```
(u.YogaSpace.Address.LocationPoints.Distance(myLocation) <= 8047)
```